# How to increase a number in a form input box using php?

Tags: php, forms, input

I already wrote a function which shows which number in two different input boxes is bigger in comperison. Furthermore, it shows if the input boxes are emptey now I want through clicking the submit button that these numbers which are written in the input boxes increase about +1.
How can I do this? (please don't hate so much I know it is a little bit basic stuff)

PHP:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
function myFunction() {

$x = (int)$_POST['demo'];
$y = (int)$_POST['name'];

if ($x>$y) {
    echo "Zahl A ist größer als Zahl B";
}

elseif ($x<$y) {
    echo "Zahl B ist größer als Zahl A";
}

else{
    echo "Trage eine Zahl ein in jedes Feld";
}
}
myFunction();
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
      <p>Zahl:</p>
     <input name="demo" type="text">
     <input name="name" type="text">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

Comment: Take the value you receive, add 1 to it … and output it again. Sorry, but this is more than basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a solution

```
<?php

$a = 0;
$b = 0;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $x = (int)$_POST['demo'];
    $y = (int)$_POST['name'];

    echo $x.", ".$y;

    $a = (int)$_POST['demo'] + 1;
    $b = (int)$_POST['name'] + 1;

    if ($x>$y) {
        echo "Zahl A ist größer als Zahl B";
    }

    elseif ($x<$y) {
        echo "Zahl B ist größer als Zahl A";
    }

    else{
        echo "Trage eine Zahl ein in jedes Feld";
    }
}

?>

<form method="post">
      <p>Zahl:</p>
     <input name="demo" type="text" value="<?php echo $a; ?>">
     <input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $b; ?>">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to increase them just in your php code so you can use them later or do you actually want to increase the number the user **sees** in the input box? For the first case, just add

```
$x++;
$y++;
```

where you want them to be increased. For the second case you could display the html form within the php page and then just display the increased numbers as value for your input fields.